# Powermock testing a static method with other methods of other class in it to return null

Tags: java, junit4, easymock, powermock

My problem is mocking and testing a method which instantiates other classes and calls their method. For project security I will only not go into details. The method to be tested is launch() method of A. The test specs wanted to make the b.methodOfB return null. another test spec would be for c.getinput() method to return null

```
public class A{

    public static void launch()
    {
       //instantiation of other classes that will be used
       B b = new B();
       C c = new C();

       //class C has a method that gets user information from the console and returns a string
       //i would like to mock c.getinput() to return null
       while (c.getinput().compareToIgnoreCase("q") != 0) {
           //would also like to mock the b.methodOfB() to return null for testing im having a hard time doing this
           b.methodOfB();//returns something not null
       }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit testing code using PowerMockito.

```
@Runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public void class ATest
{

  public void testLaunch()
  {
     B b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
     C c = PowerMockito.mock(C.class);
     PowerMockito.when(c.getInput()).thenReturn(null);
     PowerMockito.when(b.methodOfB()).thenReturn(null);
     // now call your methods 
   }

 }
```

If you have to mock static method in a class , you have to use mockStatic(Classname.class) and then mock the methods as above.

Note : I have not compiled this code . I just typed in the reply. If you like vote up :)